# The client asked me to find the figure in the image uploaded to make it as the logo image , what does that mean?

Tags: client-relations

The client asked me to find the figure in the image uploaded to make it as the logo image , what does that mean ???[image]

Comment: Ask your client?

Comment: Seriously, your takeaway here should not be whatever answer scores the best below, but that if you cannot communicate such a simple issue as this with your client then you need to improve your communication skills immediately.

Answer (score 3):

There is *no* shame in asking a client to clarify something they've asked you to do. In fact that is really part of *your job*.

If you don't understand what's being directed, you need to get more information.

Like *everyone* here, I can *guess* at what your question means *to me* however that may or may not be what your client means.

In short....

## Ask your client if there's direction you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

This is a guess. The client wants to use that robot or game character in his logo and wants you to somehow take it from somewhere.

Only the client knows, is he going to pay for it and has he thought anything about copyright and licensing.

You should tell him:

1. you can try to find, where it can be copied and who owns the copyright. This work costs XXX/hour (your rate). The price is based solely on used time and it's without any quarantee of useful results.
2. you can also draw a copy of it, if needed; for ex. because vector version isn't available, it costs YYY
3. you are NOT going to help to steal it. You make a copy or insert it to something that the client can publish or distribute only after the client gives a signed paper where he assures

   - he has copyright owner's permission to use it for purpose ZZZ (=exact way to use)
   - you are hired only to execute physically his usage and
   - he pays all licensing costs of the usage, you have no part in the licensing

The character is printed in that paper to make clear the subject.

Offer to the client also an alternative - your own creation.